# How can I constrain rotation of an a-camera (aframe)?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

For example 
1.to allow rotation about z-axis only from -70 to 70 degree or 
2.to block rotation about about an arbitrary axis

thnx

Comment: For Point 1 : consider z axis as an arbitrary axis.
For Point 2 : you want camera should only rotate around arbitrary axis not translate right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy and paste the look-controls component: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/look-controls.js

As I have done at https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/blob/master/components/reverse-look-controls/index.js

And when the component goes to update the orientation, you can constrain it yourself with something like `Math.min/Math.max`